# Как проверить столкновение в ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Допустим, у меня есть уровень с объектами разной формы. Подскажите, как сделать коллизии?
В as2 все было очень просто `this.hitTest(object, true);` и можно было проверять объекты неправильной формы.
Подскажите, похожую функцию в as3, `hiTestObject` не подходит.
И ещё интересует, как лучше проверить множество объектов на столкновение, например, с главным героем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения "правильных" столкновений могу посоветовать физический движок [Box2D](http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/). [Пример использования](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/10/26/platform-game-basics-using-box2d/).

В чистом ас3 со столкновениями туговато.

Существует способ проверять точки через hitTestPoint(), скажем по 2-4 с каждой стороны объекта, но это опять таки прямоугольник. Более сложные формы не универсальны.

Множество столкновений можно реализовать через группы/массивы. Загонять в массивы enemys/goodies. Потом простым перебором.

По уму надо смотреть в сторону готовых игровых движков. Например большинство игровых проблем решены в Flixel - http://flixel.org/features.html . В том числе работа с группами и столкновениями.

Comment: Да, движки это хорошо но желательно было бы сделать свою проверку) сейчас мучаю битмап.
Фликсел порадовал, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Может вы не правильно пишите функцию `hitTestObject();`
Обычно делается так:

```
if(enemy.hitTestObject(hero)){
    trace('enemy hit enemy');
}
```

А если нужно проверить множество объектов, то тогда через массив